# How to change read-only permission of external hard drive

Tags: raspberry-pi, chmod

I have an FreeAgent GoFlex Drive that I would like to save data to via my Raspberry Pi 3.  I'm able to view jpegs from the drive, but not save data to it.  When I attempt to change permissions, I get the following error:

```
chmod 755 FreeAgent\ GoFlex\ Drive/
chmod: changing permisssons of 'FreeAgent GoFlex Drive/': Read-only file system
```

What do I do in order to be able to save to it?  I have data on there, so formatting is not an option.

Comment: Please post the output of `mount | grep FreeAgent` while it is mounted.

Comment: `mount | grep FreeAgent\ GoFlex\ Drive/ ` gives no output

Answer (score 1):

This could work:
Try to dismount (can be done with umount) it, restart PC and login as root or do sudo chroot 755 YOUR_HARD_DISK_DRIVE (if it gets mounted, dismount it again) and then manually mount it (create a subdir in /mnt/ example "cd /mnt/, mkdir mntpnt1") then use mount command to mount it in /mnt/ (or wherever you like).

Also is there any documentation from Hard Disk Drive's manufacturer? If yes, make sure you read it.

Answer (score 1):

Viola `mount -o remount,rw /path/to/remount`

Comment: `sudo mount -o remount,rw FreeAgent\ GoFlex\ Drive/` gives following error: `mount: cannot remount /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected`

Comment: It might have a hardware switch that needs to be flipped, have you looked at the user manual?